# Guardar varios registros con save() - Django

Tags: django

La idea es guardar datos pero un campo ir cambiándolo...

```py
for i in range(len(listanueva)):
                    dato_fijo1 = form.cleaned_data['campo1']
                    dato_fijo2 = form.cleaned_data['campo2']
                    dato_fijo3 = form.cleaned_data['campo3']
                    dato_variable = i
                    paquete = MyForm({
                        'campo1': dato_fijo1,
                        'campo2': dato_fijo2,
                        'campo3': dato_fijo3,
                        'campo_variable': dato_variable,
                        })
                    paquete.save()
```

no puedo poner todo el codigo, no se porque

Comment: def enter_view(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
  form = MyForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             dato_form = form.cleaned_data['correo']
             listanueva = Ordenarcorreos(lista)
             for i in range(len(listanueva)):
                 dato_fijo1 = form.cleaned_data['campo1']
                 dato_fijo2 = form.cleaned_data['campo2']
                 dato_fijo3 = form.cleaned_data['campo3']
                 dato_variable = i
                 paquete = MyForm({

Comment: 'campo1': dato_fijo1,
                     'campo2': dato_fijo2,
                     'campo3': dato_fijo3,
                     'campo_variable': dato_variable,
                     })
                 paquete.save() 
             return redirect('home') 
     else: 
         form = MyForm() 
     return render(request, 'home.html', { 
         'form': form, 
     })

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta que agregues que tipo de form estas usando si forms.Form o forms.ModelForm y su codigo.

Suponiendo que estés usando un forms.Form, puedes usar el método "create" del modelo para ir creando los nuevos objetos de esta manera:

```
def enter_view(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = MyForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            dato_form = form.cleaned_data['correo'] 
            listanueva = Ordenarcorreos(lista) 
            for i in range(len(listanueva)): 
                dato_fijo1 = form.cleaned_data['campo1'] 
                dato_fijo2 = form.cleaned_data['campo2'] 
                dato_fijo3 = form.cleaned_data['campo3'] 
                dato_variable = i 
                # Cambiar MiModelo por tu nombre de modelo e importarlo
                MiModelo.objects.create(campo1=dato_fijo1, campo2=dato_fijo2, campo3=dato_fijo3, campo_variable=dato_variable)
            return redirect('home') 
                
        else: 
            form = MyForm() 

    return render(request, 'home.html', { 'form': form, })
```

Comment: en forms.py estoy usando forms.ModelForm, veré de aplicar esos cambios, muchas gracias.